# Find percentage value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column which contains some numeric values in my table. I need to find 85% of each value and display it in a column next to it.

Answer (score 2):

use a query something like this:

`select percent, percent * .85 as new_percent from your_table`.